# How do I save data to the iPhone properly and securely? 

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, objective-c

I'm creating a game using Cocos2D (objective-c) and it has come to the point where I have to save data to local storage, like high scores and similar stuff.

I know that `NSUserDefaults` is not a good option because it isn't encrypted. I would like to know what is or what are the best/simple methods of saving data with security to the iPhone to avoid a casual hacker from changing the score.

Comment: Fundamentally this is the same question as http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23296/how-can-i-protect-my-save-data-from-casual-hacking  There shouldn't be anything specific to the iPhone that would make the answer any different, unless there's some kind of built-in mechanism in the SDK for doing so.

Comment: There is such a mechanism built into iOS (the Keychain), but it's really intended for passwords and probably isn't a good fit for saved games.

Comment: @JohnCalsbeek, So better not to use keychain?

Comment: @marcg11 Yeah, it's not intended for chunks of secure content, just for passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't try to encrypt the file. It makes writing and parsing more complicated (eg. you'll have to work around the built-in mechanisms) and it's also much harder to debug, because you can't have a look what your app just wrote there.

Instead just write to the application directory or use `NSUserDefaults`.

Now this doesn't address your issue about hacking of these files. To add some protection I'd suggest that you create a hash (checksum) of that data and store it in the Keychain. Then every time you read the data back in, you compare the stored hash to the one that you'll get from the read data. If it's the same, everything is fine. If the data has been altered, your checksums won't match and you can do any counter-measure you'd like...

Comment: How exactly this cheksum works? I know with NSUserDefaults I can set the score by doing the following `setInteger:score forKey:@"myScore"];` When you say store the cheksum in the keychain , whatt do you mean?

Comment: By checksum/hash, I mean something like [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5). Then you generate a hash of your data (eg. everything that gets written to the file). If the data changes, it won't generate the same hash...

Comment: Maybe [this article](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/core-services/create-md5-hash-from-nsstring-nsdata-or-file.html) will help you.

Comment: Nice article. I won't save a lot of things, so it's better to send a string instead of NSData, ,right? That string is just all the things i want to save and more (like the udid, etc) concatenated?

Comment: I'd use an `NSDictionary` as container for your settings. You can easily write that to a `.plist` file or serialize it to `NSData`. That's going to be flexible, even when you plan to write more contents later on.

Comment: aren't plists easy to "hack"? because saving data to a plists and using NSUserDefaults is something completly diferent right?

Comment: As I have written in my anser: The whole idea of my proposal is not to secure the `plist` but store a checksum at a secure place (Keychain). If the checksum from the keychain doesn't match the checksum of the loaded `plist` data, then somebody changed the `plist`.. then you can show a "cheater" message on screen or do whatever else you prefer. But quite honestly: why even bother securing a file for a single-player game?

Comment: oh, so I store my data in a plist, and the checksum using NSUserDefaults? It's not singleplayer game, I'm planing on using gamecenter.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're worried about secure data, I would encrypt it yourself regardless of where it's stored. Since I don't do iOS programming I don't really know where you can store it but I would suggest also storing it online if possible. That way, you always have control over the data. But, if that's not an option, (if it lets you) store it in the app folder encrypted. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the players score than NSUserDefaults is the best option to store it as no one can change it except your application itself.

There are other options available in iOS devices, like in a file in the documents folder of your application in the form of plist, sqlite3 or normal text file, which can be modified by iExplorer application for mac and windows. But you don't have to worry about that as most of the iPhone users won't go to that much level to just change their score. They are gonna play ur game instead, if they like it.

So you don't need to worry about the where to store your application data. But even if you are worried than there are some encryption classes available in iOS framework that you can use to store your data.

Comment: The thing is that I'm new to iOs programming, and I can't find a good source of code of encryption, or the ones I find aren't very clear for me.